# node canvas on alpine within docker

Tags: docker, alpine-linux, node-canvas

I'm trying to install node canvas (https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas) on Alpine within docker.

These are (parts of) my Dockerfile:

```
# Use node/alpine image for final build
FROM keymetrics/pm2:latest-alpine as app

# install dependencies for canvas
RUN apk --no-cache --virtual .build-deps add \
        python \
        make \
        g++ \
        gcc \
    && apk --no-cache --virtual .canvas-build-deps add \
        build-base \
        cairo-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        pango-dev \
        giflib-dev \
        pixman-dev \
        pangomm-dev \
        libjpeg-turbo-dev \
        freetype-dev \
    && apk --no-cache add \
        pixman \
        cairo \
        pango \
        giflib
RUN apk add --update  --repository http://dl-3.alpinelinux.org/alpine/edge/testing libmount ttf-dejavu ttf-droid ttf-freefont ttf-liberation ttf-ubuntu-font-family fontconfig

# Install dependencies
RUN npm install --prod
RUN npm rebuild canvas --build-from-source
```

When I try to boot my docker container the following error appears:

```
Error: Error relocating /var/www/app/node_modules/canvas/build/Release/canvas.node: FcConfigGetCurrent: symbol not found
    at Object.Module._extensions..node (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:775:18)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/node_modules/canvas/lib/bindings.js:3:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:745:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:626:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:566:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:558:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:663:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/app/node_modules/canvas/lib/canvas.js:9:18)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:734:30)
```

I'm guessing that it has something to do with the fact that Alpine uses musl instead of glibc but I thought that rebuilding canvas from source `npm rebuild canvas --build-from-source` would be enough.

I've already tried most suggestions from https://github.com/Automattic/node-canvas/issues but none is working for me.

Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

OK, here's an answer--a way to install **node-canvas v2.5** under the official **node:10.16.0-alpine** Docker image.  As you probably know, the error you posted, "Error relocating...canvas.node" indicates your build failed.  This is because canvas uses *glibc* but alpine uses *musl*.  Canvas needs to link to *glibc*, so you need to add it to your image.  Sasha Gerrand offers [alpine-pkg-glibc](https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc) as one way to do it.  Using his installation instructions, here's how it looks in a docker file:

```
    #  geo_core layer
    #  build on a node image, in turn built on alpine linux, Docker's official linux pulled from hub.docker.com
    FROM node:10.16.0-alpine

    #  add libraries; sudo so non-root user added downstream can get sudo
    RUN apk add --no-cache \
        sudo \
        curl \
        build-base \
        g++ \
        libpng \
        libpng-dev \
        jpeg-dev \
        pango-dev \
        cairo-dev \
        giflib-dev \
        python \
        ;

    #  add glibc and install canvas
    RUN apk --no-cache add ca-certificates wget  && \
        wget -q -O /etc/apk/keys/sgerrand.rsa.pub https://alpine-pkgs.sgerrand.com/sgerrand.rsa.pub && \
        wget https://github.com/sgerrand/alpine-pkg-glibc/releases/download/2.29-r0/glibc-2.29-r0.apk && \
        apk add glibc-2.29-r0.apk && \
        npm install canvas@2.5.0
        ;
```

Comment: thanks for answering. I did however switch to debian-slim as our docker image. We ran in to some other issues which forced us to switch images. I will however, accept your answer :) looks like it is the solution.

Comment: I got a few error during the build but it seems fine when running my app

Answer (score 21):

```
FROM node:12-alpine

WORKDIR /app

RUN apk add --update --no-cache \
    make \
    g++ \
    jpeg-dev \
    cairo-dev \
    giflib-dev \
    pango-dev \
    libtool \
    autoconf \
    automake

COPY package.json ./

RUN npm install

COPY . .
```

This worked for me. The additional packages are dependencies for sodium native.

Comment: I used this solution, it works perfectly !

Comment: Glad to help @HugoSohm

Comment: Thanks god you are right! I did so many search before finding this one, there are a lot of outdated version everywhere. I confirm this apk instruction is working for node:18-alpine

Answer (score 5):

I ran into the same error installing canvas@2.6.0 on docker base with alpine and nodev8.9.4. I was able to fix it by upgrading to **nodev10.15.0** and **alpinev3.10**. It works without having to install the alpine-pkg-glibc package. Ofcourse, you'll still have to install these packages:

```
apk add --no-cache \
    python \
    g++ \
    build-base \
    cairo-dev \
    jpeg-dev \
    pango-dev \
    musl-dev \
    giflib-dev \
    pixman-dev \
    pangomm-dev \
    libjpeg-turbo-dev \
    freetype-dev \
    && npm install canvas@2.6.0
```

Comment: It worked for me with FROM node:14.15.1-alpine

Comment: worked for me on amd64/node:14.18.3-alpine -- this guy is a legend -- HUGE SHOUTOUT to you sionelt! THANK YOU!

FYI you can remove these deps after you’ve compiled the native Node extensions

Comment: Works for me as well with `Alpine Linux v3.16` and  node v18.12.0

Answer (score 0):

The "rebuild" is not worked also with me. But this modification will, you can try (please ignore some of my other packages for other libraries)

```
FROM node:8.16.0-alpine
....

RUN apk --update --no-cache --virtual build-dependencies add \
    python python-dev py-pip \ 
    build-base make g++ pkgconfig autoconf automake bash \ 
    imagemagick cairo-dev jpeg-dev pango-dev giflib-dev pixman-dev pangomm-dev libjpeg-turbo-dev freetype-dev \ 
    libc6-compat \  
  && apk --no-cache add \
    pixman cairo pango giflib libjpeg \
....
# Remove the canvas in package.json
RUN npm install canvas@2.0.0-alpha.12 --build-from-source
RUN npm install --prod
```

Answer (score -1):

This is not an answer--sorry--but you may need a workaround until this gets resolved.  I have temporarily backed up to the ***node:8.1.0-alpine*** image.  Under this image I am able to ***npm install canvas@1.6.7***.  It throws a flood of warnings but I get a working image I can deploy.  Now I'm hoping someone can figure out a real answer to this issue and we can get canvas 2.5 running under node:10.16.0-alpine.  Hope it helps.