# Metaplex dockerized dev server crash randomly

Tags: docker, webpack, apple-m1

On my MacOs I setup docker container with [metaplex](https://docs.metaplex.com/create-store/installation) (more setup details are in this older separate [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/70506840/860099)) development environment (webpack, react) - and when I change something in code, or not change nothing, randomly (usually after 1-2 min) following error appears:

```sh
@oyster/common: 5:05:37 PM - Found 0 errors. Watching for file changes.
web: Killed
web: error Command failed with exit code 137.
web: info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
lerna ERR! yarn run start exited 137 in 'web'
lerna WARN complete Waiting for 1 child process to exit. CTRL-C to exit immediately.
error Command failed with exit code 137.
info Visit https://yarnpkg.com/en/docs/cli/run for documentation about this command.
```

This error kill docker container and page stops working - I'm unable to work. How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research I finally [found](https://github.com/benweet/stackedit/issues/1177) reason - there is no enough RAM memory. After increasing RAM memory from 2GB to 3GB problem disappear (I also increase swap file from 1 to 2GB)

[image]